# Extending arclength to two dimensions

Tags: calculus

So, I'm trying to relearn calculus from scratch -- I did all of this as a student, but am trying to re-prove everything for myself...it's been harder than I thought.

So I start with a simple problem -- a sphere of radius $1$. $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$. The arclength for this is easy: $ds = \sqrt{1+y'[x]^2}$. To get the surface area of the sphere, I integrate $ds$ over $[0,1]$: $\int x(1+y'[x]^2) dx$, and multiply by $4 \pi$ (twice $2 \pi r$) for $2x$ surface of revolution, and all is well and good. I've re-invented the wheel.

Now, I want to extend my work into 3-D. My new function is $z = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$. Now, it seems like I should do a double integral, both on $[0,1]$ to get a surface integral...(?) And I guess that's my real question. I do not want to swap to polar coordinates or otherwise simplify...I want to understand...what is my "2-D arc length" (or area length)? What is $ds$? (Or I guess, now, $dA$?). Before, $ds = \sqrt{1+y'[x]^2}$. But then, $y$ was a function of $x$. Now $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$. so $dA = \sqrt{1-(dz/dx)^2-(dz/dy)^2}$? Then $dA$ is a double integral, each over $[0,1]$ of...

I don't want to confuse anyone by going further into the cobwebs of my brain... I was doing great with my simple sphere, I'm just trying to figure out how $ds$ extends from $y[x]$, with arclength a function of $y'[x]$, to equation into an equation involving $z[x,y]$. Put differently, How do I integrate $z$ (probably twice) to get the upper hemisphere of my sphere of radius $1$? What terms do I substitute into my arclength formula to evaluate it along both the $x$ and $y$ axes to get the upper surface of my radius $1$ sphere?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: $dA(x, y) = \sqrt{1 + |\frac{dz}{dx}|^2 + |\frac{dz}{dy}|^2}$. You can derive this from the general formula for $dA$ in $n$-dimensions.

Comment: I'm a little confused even after submitting an edit to improve your query. Are you defining $y[x] = \sqrt{1-x^2}$? If so, then it's pretty strange to be using square brackets to denote a function of $x$.

Comment: Also, could [this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4558684/integrate-sqrt1x2y2/4558837#4558837) be somewhat related to what you want to integrate?

Comment: I've fixed my solution below, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula $\ell=\int_C{\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x}$ for $y=f(x)$ is a specific case of the more general formula for a line integral for $C$ parametrizable as $\boldsymbol{r}(t)=(x(t),y(t))$:

$$\ell = \int_C{\mathrm{d}s}=\int_D{\left\lVert\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right\rVert \, \mathrm{d}t}=\int_D{\sqrt{\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2}\mathrm{d}t}$$

when $x=t$.

The similar formula for a surface integral, for a surface parametrizable as $\boldsymbol{r}(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$ is

$$A = \iint_S{\mathrm{d}A} = \iint_D{\left\lVert \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{r}}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{r}}{\partial v} \right\rVert \mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v}$$

We can parametrize your surface as $\boldsymbol{r}(\phi,\theta)=(\cos{(\theta)} \sin{(\phi)}, \sin{(\theta)} \sin{(\phi)}, \cos{(\phi)})$.

Then, we integrate over $D = [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \times [0,2\pi]$.

$$\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{r}}{\partial \theta} = (-\sin{(\theta)}\sin{(\phi)}, \cos{(\theta)}\sin{(\phi)}, 0), \quad\quad \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{r}}{\partial \phi} = (\cos{(\theta)}\cos{(\phi)}, \sin{(\theta)}\cos{(\phi)}, -\sin{(\phi)})$$

$$A = \iint_D{\left\lVert \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{r}}{\partial \phi} \times \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{r}}{\partial \theta} \right\rVert \mathrm{d}\phi\,\mathrm{d}\theta} = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\int_0^{2\pi}{\sin{(\phi)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\phi} = 2\pi\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin{(\phi)} \,\mathrm{d}\phi} = 2\pi$$

Comment: Whoops, thought your surface was a paraboloid, gimme a sec to fix it.

Comment: Thank you! I think my bigger question, which is answered nowhere on the internet, is...how do I do this in purely cartesian coordinates? I have mathematica. I have NDSolve. I do not need to resort to theta and phi. I want all an all x, y, z formal solution, which I was able to do with just x and y. Why must I resort to different coordinates?

Comment: You can absolutely do it in purely Cartesian coordinates! If you instead parametrize the surface as $\boldsymbol{r}(x,y) = (x,y,\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2})$, and follow the above approach it will still work. You'll then integrate over $\{\, (x,y) \mid x \in [-1,1],\, -\sqrt{1 - x^2} \le y \le \sqrt{1 - x^2}\,\}$ to get your area.

Comment: Lemmon, you have solved it. Briefly, to respond to Accelerator's question, square brackets are Mathematica artifacts (not denominations of functionals as traditionally used), that's just Mathematica-speak.  Thanks Lemmon.